# Redirect non-members to about/intro page

Tags: login, buddypress, private, members

I´m making a small wordpress/buddypress community site where I want all content except an about page to be for members only.

I need to do a redirect to the about-page for all non-logged in users. When users log in (from the sidebar) they should end up on the blog/frontpage.

How can I achive this? I tried some different members-plugins for buddypress and wordpress but none of them did exactly what I wanted, or didn´t work with other important plugins (like WP-FB-autoconnect).

I´m guessing this is pretty easy to do with custom code in the header or functions file. But I´m not really a coder so I would like som help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your theme's headr.php file and add at the top

```
<?php
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect(get_permalink(123));
    exit;
}
?>
```

just change 123 to the id of your about page, or replace `get_permalink(123)` with the about page URL example:

```
<?php
if( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect('http://mydomain.com/about');
    exit;
}
?>
```